# Cannot get wordpress child-theme css to load/enqueue after plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

I used a plugin to auto-generate a child theme and necessary files, and it did a good job...my new style.css loads after the parent and works great. the problem is that I have a plugin that requires heavy modification to it's injected divs, and it is a nightmare to overwrite anything because they !important the entire sheet, so I have to work around it.

I'm trying to enqueue my child-theme style.css after the plugin using a priority 99 thing I found on another thread here, and it isn't doing anything. All I did was append to the end of my child functions.php.

Potential issue 1: I did not remove the previous code to enquee this css file...do I need to do that? I thought maybe it would just re-enqueue it if it got to this new code at the end of the file. But maybe it does it once and ignores my code since it's already done.

Potential issue 2: Code error on my part. If my style.css is in the same folder as my functions.php I refer to the file as just 'style.css' right? I assume so because of relative locations because I was not sure if PHP required something that I am unaware of.

Here is my code that is not working.

```
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 99 );
```

I also saw this in my functions.php...it's weird because it looks like it's trying to enqueue a parent theme css file, but the relative location points to the child theme. Very confusing. it already had the same add_action priority thing in it from the thing I posted above, so I just change the number to 99, but it also didn't work. It was set to 10.

```
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'font-awesome-5-free','saasland-dark-support','bootstrap','themify-icon','saasland-elementor','saasland-remove-animation','magnific-popup','eleganticons','saasland-wpd','saasland-main','saasland-elements','saasland-comments','saasland-footer','saasland-gutenberg' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 99 );
```

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[get_template_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) will always refer to the parent theme folder for assets.

[get_stylesheet_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) will refer to the "current" theme folder for assets (which could be the parent or the child, depending on where it is called).

If you are enqueueing style.css file for the child theme then,

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'child-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```